# OpenCL: Returning std::future instead of blocking with clFinish

Tags: c++, asynchronous, opencl

I'm new to OpenCL but there is a thing that annoys me, at the moment i end every OpenCL function with `clFlush` which is according to the standard blocking. Is there a way to asynchronize things with returning a `std::future` or to write a hand-written `my::craft::future`, allowing to wait only if necessary?

Comment: _at the moment i end every OpenCL function with clFlush which is according to the standard blocking._ Then read [clFlush](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clFlush.html) again because you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

clFlush doesn't block, clFinish does. 
"clFlush only guarantees that all queued commands to command_queue will eventually be submitted to the appropriate device There is no guarantee that they will be complete after clFlush returns. " https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clFlush.html

You can use clSetEventCallback to call a function when something has finished.
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetEventCallback.html